# High frequency switching MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, frequency, wireless-charging

i'm having af hard time finding the proper MOSFET for my wireless power transfer. I need a MOSFET which can easily do 100kHz without overheating and with minimal power dissipation. I'm currently using IRLZ44N but it's not optimal.

Resistor R6 is changeable, but i'm keeping it on 10 ohm, which draws approx. 400 mA.

[image: Picture of circuit]

Comment: Most MOSFETs will easily do 100kHz if you drive the gates properly.  The overheating part is impossible for us to comment on because we don't know how much current you're putting through the FET.  If you show a schematic and some specs and waveforms you will be much more likely to get some help.

Comment: 100 kHz is not such a high frequency so an IRLZ44N can **easily** handle that **provided you use it in the correct way**. You're not showing us how you use that MOSFET. Include a detailed **schematic** to show us what you're doing. It does not matter what MOSFET you use if you use it **incorrectly**.

Comment: There are two sources of heating in a FET, the dissipation from continuous current, as a result of the voltage drop across the FET (at the gate drive voltage you supply it) and the current you put through it, and the switching losses, which will depend on how you drive it. You'll need to provide some more detail to narrow down your optimization.

Comment: The IRLZ44N is a fast switching MOSFET in its self. So if you experiencing inefficiencies with this component then you not using it for its intended purpose or you are not connecting it in the correct way. I have used this MOSFET before at 550 kHz and experienced minimal overheating and a minimal voltage drop across the drain and source. I did, however, add a heatsink, well because it is cheap and is an added safety feature.

Comment: Absolute max Vgs for the IRLZ44N is +/- 16V, so switching +24V to the gate relative to ground/source will probably destroy the MOSFET.

Comment: It's possible that the 100kHz signal is not a perfect square wave but a sine wave (too much impedance and/or capacitance before the gate, thought the 220 ohm resistor is not causing this). Check with an oscilloscope. If it's the case add a shmidtt trigger just before the gate resistor. A perfect square wave will reduce the time when the gate is between two states (neither on or off) and therefore heating during this time. Just an idea,

Comment: Thanks everyone, i got the problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use MOSFT GATE-DRIVERS. Some come in TO-220 heat-sink-tab packages, to provide transient currents of 9/12 amps. I recall Microchip has some.

If you explore this path, you must keep the VDD (12 or 15 volts) high enough the huge internal FETS have enough gate voltage to remain deep in triode/resistive region of operation.

At these current levels, inductance in ground leads will be a killer, because internally the currents switch in 5nanoseconds or less in the chain of inverters.

If you allow a centimeter of wiring --- call that 10 nanoHenries --- the spike will be

Vspike = L * dI/dT

Vspike = 10nH * 12 amps/5nanoSeconds

Vspike = 24 volts.

In other words, **USE A GROUND PLANE**